# What is the protocol for extracting Protease Onion?

Tags: enzymes, protocol, purification, vegetable, salt

I am Investigating the protease concentration in certain fruits and vegetables. I am unable to find the protocols for the extraction from onions. I want to purify my protein using the ammonium sulphate (salting out) followed by dialysis. I am specifically concerned about the mass of ammonium sulphate that is required and the amount of water I should dissolve it in.

Comment: If no protocol exists, you would typically increase ammonium sulfate in stepwise amounts and assay for activity. You can somewhat purify your protein this way. Or you could just add some arbitrary amount like 75% and see what happens. I use [this calculator](http://www.encorbio.com/protocols/AM-SO4.htm).